# How to program to only input words and not integers on Python

Tags: python, integer

In my program, I wish to make the input to be words and not integers, and the inputted words are put into an array. The following variables are already declared.When I run my test data, numbers are accepted into the array.

```
i=o
for i in range (carers):
    nm=input("Enter name")
    carernm.append[nm]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `isdigit` to check if your string contains digits

Example 1

```
print( all( not c.isdigit() for c in "String doesn't contain any numbers." ) )
True
```

Example 2

```
print( all( not c.isdigit() for c in "String 2 doesn't contain any numbers." ) )
False
```